# hide certain content based of an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, addeventlistener

I cannot find the right solution how hide a certain content on new part of page generated from PHP. (I am new in javascript)

I have a page, which loads new content below the actual, if a visitor scrolling down (like on Facebook.)

Each time, when a new content will displayed, I want run a function, which will hide certain content on the page.

Here is the code which loads new content. This works great.

```js
(function() {

  var $loadMore = $('.load-more').first();

  if (!$loadMore.get(0)) {
   return;
  }

  var timeout;

  var $loadMoreLink = $loadMore.children('a'),
   $list = $loadMore.prev('ul');

  $loadMoreLink.on('click', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   getMore();
  });


  function checkForMore() {
   if (($window.scrollTop() + $window.height()) > ($list.offset().top + $list.height())) {
    getMore();
   }
  }

  function getMore() {
   if (!$loadMoreLink.is(':visible')) {
    return;
   }

   $loadMoreLink.attr('hidden', true);

   $.get($loadMoreLink.attr('href'), function(response) {
    $list.append(response);

    var moreUrl = $list.children().last().data('more-url');

    if (moreUrl) {
     $loadMoreLink.attr('href', moreUrl);
     $loadMoreLink.removeAttr('hidden');
    }
    else {
     $loadMore.attr('hidden', true);
    }
    console.log(moreUrl)
   });
  }
  

  $window.on('scroll', function() {
   if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
   }

   timeout = setTimeout(checkForMore, 50);
  });

  checkForMore();
 })();
```

Here is my code, with help of which I want to hide certain content. That does not work :(. I have tried really much, and spent many days on that.

```js
var hideUnity = document.getElementsByClassName("load-more");
for (var i = 0; i < hideUnity.length, i++) {
    hideUnity[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (something && something) {
            $(document).ready(function(){  
                $("li.unity").hide();
            });
          }
    });
}
```

Link to loading file at page
`<div class="load-more">
<a href="http://www.webpage.com/loadmore.php?lastid=70&type=most&lang=en">Load more</a>
</div>`

Can someone help me, please? :). Thanks.

Comment: Did you define `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">`? Because you used JQuery in there.

Comment: yes, of course. What i do not know is, how I have wtite the function.

Comment: `.hide();` method is used exactly as you've written up there. But what's with `if (something && something)`? What's the condition?

Comment: Yes, like @kmsdev answered below, you don't need to mix Javascript and JQuery. Why did you do it like that?

Comment: Sorry I thought, that when it works, i do not need write there the conditions. Well, there is '(unityMissing && isChrome)'. Both work great. On the first loaded part of the page (when you come there) the hiding function is functional. However, I need run it also each time, when a new content is loaded (= load-more event., see the first script)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a reason to mix native js and jQuery, but you can do your function easily using the framework:

```
$(function(){
    $(".load-more").on('click', function(){
        // now $(this) represents clicked object while $('.load-more') still represents all elements with provided class
        if( whateveryouwant ){
            $("li.unity").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit**

If you need to use a delegated event, just replace

```
$(".load-more").on('click', function(){....
```

by

```
$(document).on('click', '.load-more', function(){....
```

Comment: I have similar function which works. Anyway, I need run this function more times, each time, when new content is loaded. I need load the content (this works), and when the content is loaded, run the function for hide games (this does not work). Here, I do not know, how i can set, that the hiding function will run each time, when load-more occurs.

I think, there must be some EventListener (if load-more, then run the function), but i do not know how write it. see the second example.  BTW, I can create a page, where it will visible.

Comment: I am not sure at all, but it is possible that you are looking for delegated events. I updated my question.

Comment: Hi, For now, I will try test an simple solution, when I will load first page, verify user's plugins, and hide content which is non-functional for him. (this works great already now.).
The problem with loaded content below I want to try solve so, that I will save values of user plugins into cookie, and then I will on this base load only useful content for a user via php (the content is loaded later than the first javascript). => I will not need hide anything, how I wanted. Do you think, this can work? This will be moreover more effective, as per me.

Comment: I am still having some difficulty to understand properly what you are trying to do. Can you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to work on it?

Comment: Maybe are you looking for something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/3bwa3wgr/)**? I oriented your script to objects, I think is more readable. Take a look and maybe we can work from here.

Comment: Thanks for all advices. Anyway, for now we did it via php. If I find a solution how to do it via JS, I will write it here :). (I am beginner in JS)